# PyInstaller unbuffered stdio

Tags: python, docker, pyinstaller, stdio

## Problem

Docker image sizes should commonly be as small as possible. Using full-blown environments like a [standard python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/) image results often, with all dependencies installed, in heavily bloated images. Packaging python into stand-alone executables (e.g. using pyinstaller) is a perfect way of reducing image sizes and overall complexity.

**Environment**: `python3.6`, `pyinstaller==3.4`

The problem arising is, that python uses per default buffered stdio. This can be mitigated by running python scripts with `python -u ...`. But becomes inaccessible when using pyinstaller.

According to the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.4/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options) it should be possible to add run-time options, such as `u`, `v` and `W ...` to the executable generated. But unfortunately in reality it doesn't seem to work. Both, `v` and `W`, work normally, but `u` seems to be completely ignored.

The following snippet shows the usage:

```
...
exe = EXE(...
          [('u', None, 'OPTION')],
          name="myapp",
          ...)
...
```

Is this flag still valid? Since the others work - has it been removed without notice or update of the docs?

Are there alternatives to disable buffering of stdio (with pyinstaller or as well externally), *without* modifying the python code, like [so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107705/disable-output-buffering)?

## Why would that be needed?

Buffered IO is to be avoided, when running docker swarm services. In order to make the executable properly log in real-time to the docker daemon, it's necessary to attach a shell. But the attaching of a tty shell to the swarm tasks makes working with the logs much, much more complicated if even impossible.

Answer (score 0):

At least it is broken on Windows (See [issue on github](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1441)) and it’s not in the [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#options).

Answer (score 0):

This [pull request](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/pull/5597) fixed the issue.

The '-u' option will set the `Py_UnbufferedStdioFlag` flag to enable unbuffered stdio mode in Python library.

This [doc](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#giving-run-time-python-options) shows how to enable the runtime option with **spec file**.

```
options = [ ('u', None, 'OPTION') ]
a = Analysis( ...
        )
...
exe = EXE(pyz,
  a.scripts,
  options,   <--- added line
  exclude_binaries=...
  )
```

NOTE:

> This enables unbuffered binary layer of stdout and stderr streams in
> all supported Python versions, while unbuffered text layer requires
> Python 3.7 or later.