# Pyinstaller: setting unbuffered stdio on python 2.7 on Windows

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyinstaller, stdio

I have a Windows 10 python script that I usually run using the following command:-

```
python -u my_python_application.py
```

The `-u` option is used to force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally [unbuffered](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u). This gives my application an instantaneous feel, and without it there is a delay where data is logged after the operation occurs.

I am now trying to create an executable through Pyinstaller. So far everything is working as expected and I can generate an executable which I can run without any major issues. However, the generated executable does not have the unbuffered stdio option, and as a result my application is not as instantaneous/responsive as its non-executable form. So my question is: **Is there anyway to force stdio to be totally unbuffered when using Pyinstaller?**

I have found similar unanswered posts here:-

- [Pyinstaller unbuffered runtime option](https://www.mail-archive.com/pyinstaller@googlegroups.com/msg00841.html)
- [Pyinstaller unbuffered stdio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52302361/pyinstaller-unbuffered-stdio)
- [Pyinstaller examine handling of u option](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1441)

I am using Python v2.7.13 and Pyinstaller v3.6 on a Windows 10 machine.

Comment: See https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1441

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a work around than a fix, but the way I was able to get around this was by using the option flush=True when calling the print statement. In other words, I replaced all print statements in my application with a new function called app_print() as follows:-

```
#Do something
app_print("printing a generic string")
```

then I defined app_print to always flush the stdio:-

```
def app_print(sting):
    print(string, flush=True)
```

This fixed my problem and the resulting executable now has an instantaneous feel similar to how the original python script did.

More links about this:-

- [How can I flush the output of the print function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230751/how-can-i-flush-the-output-of-the-print-function)
- [How to flush output of print function](https://newbedev.com/how-to-flush-output-of-print-function)
- [Python print function](http://www.trytoprogram.com/python-programming/python-built-in-functions/print/)